# Testcafe-vue-selector no data bind in component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have problem with testing my Vue component I going to use e2e testcafe with testcafe-vue-selector but some component witch I try test and they do not have any state, computed, props if they have not seen it at all :( Other components works fine.

Component

```js
 export default {
    name: 'Auth',
    inject: ['app'],
    data: () => ({
      form: 'login'
    }),
    mounted() {
      if (this.$route.params.resetPasswordCode) {
        this.form = 'set-password'
      }
    },
    methods: {
      updateFormType(form) {
        this.form = form
      }
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters({
        session: 'user/session'
      }),
      matchFormType() {
        return (form) => {
          return this.form === form
        }
      },
      title() {
        const form = this.form

        switch (form) {
          case 'login':
            return 'form.action.login.into.curse'
          case 'signup':
            return 'form.action.signup.into.curse'
          case 'remind-password':
            return 'form.action.remind.password'
          case 'set-password':
            return 'form.action.set.password'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

e2e in Testcafe

```js
const VueSelector = require(require('path').resolve('./src/tests/VueSelector'))

fixture('Auth.vue').page('http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth')

test('correct render Auth', async t => {
  const auth = VueSelector('Auth')
  const authInstance = await auth.getVue()

  const { state, props, computed } = authInstance

  console.log(state, props, computed)
})
```

Comment: I need to know testcafe, testcafe-vue-selectors, vue.js versions you are using so that I can determine the cause of the issue.
It is also important how the component is embedded in your application. That is why it would be very helpful to get a small example to reproduce the problem. Would you please provide it?